# React Native strange background color issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native

testing a simple login screen in React Native through Expo created with CRNA, I can see it just fine in Android Emulator, but in iPhone device I see all texts and icons with a light white background color. I haven't set any background color on thoose areas through styling.

[image: Android Emulator and iOS device screenshots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying `backgroundColor:'transparent'` for the icons and `color:'white'` for the text.